# Can I run 64 bit apps in 32 bit Linux?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, emulation

There are some proprietary apps that are being provided only in 64-bit version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I think there is no way to do this, because 64bit programs are not compatible with 32bit OS, but most 32bit programs are compatible with 64bit OS. It's simply another architecture. Which program do you want to use?